# Retrieve a CSV file received over Gmail from a specific email address to a specific Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Goals of the problem:

- Retrieve the message from Gmail using the email address.
- Retrieve the CSV files from the attachment files and put them on a sheet in Google Spreadsheet. Remove 1st 2 rows from the CSV data. (Remove the past data on Google Sheets and update it with the new CSV data whenever received from the specific email address).
- Achieve this using Google Apps Script.

Already tried: [Automate a CSV file received over Gmail from a specific email id to a specific Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369823/automate-a-csv-file-received-over-gmail-from-a-specific-email-id-to-a-specific-g)

But nothing is solving the above 3 problems in specific.

```
function myFunction() {
  const messageId = "###"; // Please set the message ID of Gmail.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name you want to put the values.
  const delimiter = ","; // If your CSV data uses the specific delimiter, please set this.
  const skipRows = 2; // 2 is from your question.

  // 1. Retrieve message.
  const message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);

  // 2. Retrieve attachment files.
  const attachments = message.getAttachments();
  if (attachments.length == 0) {
    console.log("No attachment files.");
    return;
  }

  // 3. Create an array for putting to Spreadsheet from the CSV data of attachment files.
  const values = attachments.reduce((ar, e) => {
    if (e.getContentType() == MimeType.CSV || e.getName().includes(".csv")) {
      ar = [...ar, ...Utilities.parseCsv(e.getDataAsString(), delimiter).splice(skipRows)];
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (values.length == 0) {
    console.log("No values.");
    return;
  }

  // 4. Put the values to Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName); // and, you can also use. const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###spreadsheetId###").getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Tried the above code but it shows an error **Exception: Invalid argument: at myFunction(Code:8:28)**

FYI, I also want to use Sheet ID instead of Sheet Name

Comment: what is the "email ID" ? en email address? you speak about sheetID or spreadsheetID?

Comment: There is no getSheetById method and all sheetnames must be unique

Comment: @MikeSteelson Email ID is the email address and sheet id is the spreadsheet ID from the Google sheets URL.

Comment: @Cooper Okay, then the sheet name would also work.

Comment: @NikhilGupta so which did you use to get the invalid argument error? If you used the id the that's the problem

Comment: @NikhilGupta, see hereafter, I put a spreadsheet ID as parameter.

Comment: @Cooper I got the invalid argument error at GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId); I have tried using the email address and the subject but it didn't work. Let me know what has to be entered as message id?

Comment: This is the line closest to  28 `const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);` that's what I thought you were talking about.

Comment: Yeah neither the email address, nor the subject is the messageId.  You were the one that asked for finding the message from the message id so I assumed you knew what you wanted.  This was your original question `Automate a CSV file received over Gmail from a specific email id to a specific Google Sheet`

Comment: @MikeSteelson Your code worked perfectly. Can you tweak it a bit and instead of using the unread criteria can you use the subject?

Also, we'll receive an email daily from that specific email ID and the subject will have a constant string but on the left and right of that string, there might be different characters that will get updated daily. Plus please take note that only the latest email should be taken into consideration while updating the Google Sheet. Rest all before one should be ignored.

Comment: can you try again, I changed the script a bit

Comment: @MikeSteelson has:attachment subject:##### subject:###' What should be added in the first and second subject?

Comment: 2 different words if you want to be more precise, for instance if suject is `"weather forecast Dublin this week"`, you can put `subject:weather subject:Dublin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (put the spreadsheet ID, the subject -if you have multiple words please specify as in the example hereafter- and the email of the sender hereafter):

```
const getGmailAttachment = () => {
  const ssID = '############'
  const searchQuery = 'from:######@gmail.com in:inbox has:attachment subject:##### subject:###';
  const threads = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, 0, 1);
  threads.forEach(thread => {
    const message = thread.getMessages()[Number(thread.getMessageCount() - 1)];
    const attachments = message.getAttachments();
    attachments.forEach((attachment, i) => {
      if (i == 0) {
        console.log(attachment.getName())
        const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0];
        sheet.getDataRange().clearContent()
        const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString()).splice(2); // except 2 first rows
        sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

### references

[GmailApp.search](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery,-start,-max)

[search syntax](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)

[getAttachments()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getAttachments())

[Utilities.parseCsv](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv,-delimiter)